# How to use default parameter values on conjunction with HttpParameterBinding in .NET Web APIs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm using parameter binding in my .NET Web API (see the classes below). In my controller action, I have three parameters, each of which are optional (I have default values in the method parameter list). However, I cannot figure out how to make my HttpParameterBinding class ignore missing parameters. If I make a request using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3208/api/fruit?query=gr&start=0&limit=10
```

...everything works just fine. But if I use the following URL (without the `limit` parameter):

```
http://localhost:3208/api/fruit?query=gr&start=0
```

...I get the following error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'limit' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String] Get(System.String, Int32, Int32)' in 'WebAPITest.Controllers.Apis.TestController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

I've tried simply not setting a value in my HttpParameterBinder if the `Descriptor.ParameterName` doesn't show up in the `Query String`, but this produces the same error as above. Any ideas how I can get the HttpParameterBinding to just pass no value into the action method if it doesn't find a corresponding value in the request data?

---

My Web API controller looks like this:

```
[TestApi]
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("fruit")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string query = "", int start = 0, int limit = Int32.MaxValue)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fruits = new string[] {
            "Apple",
            "Banana",
            "Cherry",
            "Dragonfruit",
            "Elderberry",
            "Fig",
            "Grape",
            "Honeydew",
            "Watermelon"
        };

        return fruits.Where(f => f.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower())).Skip(start).Take(limit);
    }
}
```

My type binder looks like this:

```
public class TestTypeBinder : HttpParameterBinding
{
    public TestTypeBinder(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor) : base(descriptor) {}

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        object paramValue = ReadTypeFromRequest(actionContext);
        SetValue(actionContext, paramValue);
        TaskCompletionSource<AsyncVoid> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<AsyncVoid>();
        tcs.SetResult(default(AsyncVoid));
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private object ReadTypeFromRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string dataValue = HttpUtility
            .ParseQueryString(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query)
            .Get(Descriptor.ParameterName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataValue)) {
            if (Descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(int))
                return Convert.ToInt32(dataValue);
            else if (Descriptor.ParameterType == typeof(string))
                return dataValue;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public struct AsyncVoid { }
```

And finally, my attribute class looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class TestApiAttribute : Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
{
    public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        Func<HttpParameterDescriptor, HttpParameterBinding> tvParameterBinder = param => new TestTypeBinder(param);

        controllerSettings.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, typeof(string), tvParameterBinder);
        controllerSettings.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, typeof(int), tvParameterBinder);
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't you use int? instead of int in the function paramter

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I am using `int` in the function parameter. Unless you're thinking of a different function than I am.

Comment: i meant nullable int(int?)

Comment: That works. I assumed it will override the default value I was assigning and just give me an null `int?`, but it doesn't. Thanks. If you write that up as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use nullable int(int?) instead of just int type in your function param.